# Error raro (Extended initializer lists)

Tags: c++

Buenas gente,

Me acaba de surgir un error en este codigo bastante simple, que nunca lo había visto.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
const int tam = 10;
using namespace std;

struct Votante {
int DNI;
char nombre[40];
bool presente;
};

void carga(Votante x[]){
string nom;

for (int i=0; i<tam; i++){
    cin >> x[i].DNI;
    cin >> nom;
    strcpy(x[i].nombre, nom.c_str());   
}
}

void carga2 (Votante x[], FILE *z){
z = fopen("Padron.bin","wb");

for (int e = 0;e < tam;e++){
    fwrite(&x[e],sizeof(Votante),1,z);
}
fclose(z);
}


int main{   
Votante a[tam];
FILE *t;

carga(a);
carga2 (a, t);
}
```

Y me tira este error (La linea 35 es la del int main)

```
35  9[Warning] extended initializer lists only available with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11
```

Nunca vi este error en lo que llevo compilando todo este tiempo, y busqué y no encontré de que se podría tratar.

Saludos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ese tipo de error se da con el nuevo estilo de inicializacion usando `{ }`, pero en tu caso, tal vez piensa que estas tratando de hacer ese tipo de inicializacion, porque olvidaste los `( )` para definir `main()` como función. (la esta viendo como una variable entera)

Answer (score 3):

Estás declarando un objeto de tipo `int` con nombre `main`:

```
int main{   
Votante a[tam];
FILE *t;

carga(a);
carga2 (a, t);
}
```

Al añadir las llaves tras el nombre del objeto, el compilador cree que quieres usar una lista para inicializarlo. Seguramente querías una función `main` que devuelve `int`, así que:

```
//      vv <--- Parametros de la funcion
int main(){   
Votante a[tam];
FILE *t;

carga(a);
carga2 (a, t);
return 0; // <--- retorno de la funcion
}
```